# illegalException:: response getwriter() is already defined

Tags: java, jsp

When I'm running this code,

> illegalException:: response getwriter() is already defined.

```
<% 
            Blob image = null;
                Connection con = null;
                byte[ ] imgData = null ;
                Statement stmt = null;
                ResultSet rs = null;
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hicheck","root","root");
                    stmt = con.createStatement();
                    String s="sivabrahma";
                    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select photo from hic_relation where email=? ");  
                    ps.setString(1,"sivabrahma");
                    rs=ps.executeQuery();  
                    if (rs.next()) {
                    image = rs.getBlob(1);
                    imgData = image.getBytes(1,(int)image.length());
                    }
                     else {
                    out.println("Display Blob Example");
                    out.println("image not found for given id");
                    return;
                    }
                    // display the image
                    response.setContentType("image/gif");
                    response.getOutputStream();
                    ServletOutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
                    o.write(imgData);
                    o.flush();
                    o.close();
                      System.out.println(o.toString());
          System.out.println(imgData.toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    out.println("Unable To Display image");
                    out.println("Image Display Error=" + e.getMessage());
//                    return;
                } finally {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                    stmt.close();
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                } %>
```

When I'm retrieving image from database exception is occured.

Comment: Your question is inaccurate. 1) The name of the exception is incorrect. 2) the exception is not happening when retrieving the image from the database: it happens after that.  Also, questions asking for help with Java exceptions should always include the complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

you can get either `OutputStream` or `Writer` in a JSP not both.since JSP scriptlet already has a implicit `out` , you cannot call `getOutputStream()`

Docs  for getOutputStream() : https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream()

> IllegalStateException - if the getWriter method has been called on
>   this response

Comment: He did it in `JSP` not in `Servlet`.

Comment: @Satya JSP is converted to a  servlet

Comment: @Nazeerbasha `out` is JspWriter

Answer (score 0):

You cannot safely call `response.getOutputStream()` or `getWriter()` in a JSP.  The JSP already has created the writer for the response and will be using it.

Think about it.  How would the JSP engine know the correct interleaving for output assembled by the JSP and output the JSP code fragments ("scriptlets") wrote directly to the stream / writer.

If you want to write "directly" to the response stream in a JSP, use the implicitly declared JSP `out` variable ... which gives you the JSPWriter used by the JSP.